# Find average/ minimun/maximun

Tags: java, concurrency

```
   if (cleaningbay >=5)
   {
        long duration =5;
        try
        {    
            System.out.println("\n\t  All cleaners are busy..Please wait!..................................................................(-_-)" + bus.getName() );
            System.out.println("\n\t" + bus.getName() + "waited for " + duration );
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(duration);
            bus.notify();
            Cleaners(bus);
            bus.wait();
        }

        catch(InterruptedException iex)
        {
            iex.printStackTrace();
        } 
   }
   else if (cleaningbay < 5)
   {
        System.out.println("\n\t" + bus.getName() + "is heading to " + bus.getCleanersName() + Clock.get_time());
        cleaningbay++;
        long duration=0;
        try
        {    
            System.out.println("\n\t Cleaning in progress :" + bus.getName() + Clock.get_time() );
            duration = (long)(Math.random()* 3);

            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(duration);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException iex)
        {
            iex.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

I have these codes in different part of my program where the time is recorded in the variable "duration". I have used the "duration" variable in different methods in the same class. i wanted to know if there is a way of adding of these values "time" and find the avg/min/max

Comment: Please fix your question. Your text stands right in between your two source code parts. You code as-is will not compile because you have a dangling `else if`.

Comment: no need for the `else if (...)`; `else` has the same effect as the if clause is the negation of the initial if clause

Answer (score 1):

You can define an array to store your times before every time you change the variable, an then use it to calculate your required values.

```
List<Long> timeHistory = new ArrayList<>();
...
timeHistory.add(duration);
duration = (long)(Math.random()* 3);
```

`timeHistory` should be a global variable of your class

Answer (score 1):

If your class gets a lot of traffic, you dont want to store all times in a list, instead I would suggest you create a utility class that help you to keep track of the values you need to get MIN, MAX and AVG, something like this:

```
public class TimeHistory {
    private Long minTime = Long.MAX_VALUE; 
    private Long maxTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    private Long timeSum = 0L;
    private Long timeCount = 0L;

    public void logTime(long time){
        if(time < minTime){
            minTime = time;
        }

        if(time > maxTime){
            maxTime = time;
        }

        timeSum += time;
        timeCount++;
    }

    public Long getMinTime() {
        return minTime;
    }

    public Long getMaxTime() {
        return maxTime;
    }

    public Long getTimeAvg() {
        return timeSum / timeCount;
    }
}
```

Here you call the method **logTime**(time); every time you need, and it will take care of keep those values updated for you, then latter you just need to call the methods **getMinTime**(), **getMaxTime**() or **getTimeAvg**().

I hope it helps ;-)

Comment: The time is being saved in a variable called duration which is in a class called depot. How do import the time to this class?

Comment: Your question was: "i wanted to know if there is a way of adding of these values "time" and find the avg/min/max". You can create an instance of this TimeHistory  class, and whenever you need to register a new time, call instance.logTime, then latter you can ask for min, max and avg on that instance.